# Identification of a science fiction book about a private eye,

Tags: story-identification

I'm hoping you can help me find a book's title and author. It was a book I had seen before but didn't buy.

The plot followed a private detective set in a future where all people lived in segregated communities based on their similar interests. So for instance, scientists would live in a district where others were like-minded in their pursuit of knowledge, etc. This private detective lived in a district where people were fascinated by displaying and observing the vibrant spectrum of colours.
I'd like to express my thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 10):

That's Michael Marshall Smith's *[Only Forward](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/920395.Only_Forward)*.  The protagonist lives in the 'Color' district of the city.  His girlfriend lives in a district dedicated to Getting Things Done.  Another friend of his lives in a district dedicated to violence.

[image: Book cover]

Comment: That is brilliant. I've been trying to figure that out for so long. Cheers.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if you're happy that it's correct.